# I want to print the toast only once when event.getX()==200. But it's showing the oast multiple times after getX()>300

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

```
frmLayout.setPadding(Math.round(event.getX() - 20), 0, 0, 0);
if(event.getX()>=300)
  {
      frmLayout.setPadding(20, 100, 0, 0); 
  }//giving minimum padding 
} 
switch(event.getAction())
  {
    case 0: 
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "send Function "+event.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      // showing toast multiple yimes here
      break;
  }
if(event.getX()<=20)//give layout padding always x=20,y=100
  {
    frmLayout.setPadding(20, 100, 0, 0);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]

I believe case 0 would be checking when a pressed gesture has started. So any time the screen is touched a Toast message would be created.

So the fix would be to use a condition inside the switch with a boolean flag.

```
private boolean showToast = true; //Global var


switch (event.getAction()){
 case 0:
    if(showToast && event.getX() >= 200){
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "send Function "+event.getAction(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      showToast = false; //This will stop the condition being met the second time
      break;
   }
}
```

I haven't tested this but I'm guessing this would solve your issue.